# How to get Hourly average of Occurrences of event using TimeStamp/Date List in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, rolling-average

Sample Data for Timestamp

```
2018-04-07 07:07:17
2018-04-07 07:32:27

2018-04-07 08:36:44
2018-04-07 08:38:00
2018-04-07 08:39:29

2018-04-08 01:43:08
2018-04-08 01:43:55

2018-04-09 07:52:31
2018-04-09 07:52:42

2019-01-24 11:52:31

2019-01-24 12:52:42
2019-01-25 12:52:42
```

Expected Output:
**(2+3+2+2+1+3)/6 = 1.66**

I have to do it for weekly and monthly as well, but I can infer from the Hourly logic.

```
 // Iterate over each entry of a group
  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {
    val dateString = input(0).toString()

    val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
    val zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, dtf.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault)

    // zdt ZonedDateTime
```

I can get use all the method of ZonedDateTime

Comment: why is the question getting negative votes?

Comment: I have tried to solve this. Please upvote + accept if this resolves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to solve using below approach-

> Please note that the code is running in IST (GMT + 5.30), Therefore the dates
>   2018-04-07 07:07:17 and
>   2018-04-07 07:32:27
>   will be considered in different hours (1st in 6:30 - 7:30 and 2nd in 7:30  - 8:30)

### Code

1. **`Read the data`**

```
val spark = sqlContext.sparkSession
    val implicits = spark.implicits
    import implicits._
    val data =
      """
        |2018-04-07 07:07:17
        |2018-04-07 07:32:27
        |2018-04-07 08:36:44
        |2018-04-07 08:38:00
        |2018-04-07 08:39:29
        |2018-04-08 01:43:08
        |2018-04-08 01:43:55
        |2018-04-09 07:52:31
        |2018-04-09 07:52:42
        |2019-01-24 11:52:31
        |2019-01-24 12:52:42
        |2019-01-25 12:52:42
      """.stripMargin
    val df = spark.read
      .schema(StructType(Array(StructField("date_time", DataTypes.TimestampType))))
      .csv(data.split(System.lineSeparator()).toSeq.toDS())
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
```

Result -

```
+-------------------+
|date_time          |
+-------------------+
|2018-04-07 07:07:17|
|2018-04-07 07:32:27|
|2018-04-07 08:36:44|
|2018-04-07 08:38:00|
|2018-04-07 08:39:29|
|2018-04-08 01:43:08|
|2018-04-08 01:43:55|
|2018-04-09 07:52:31|
|2018-04-09 07:52:42|
|2019-01-24 11:52:31|
|2019-01-24 12:52:42|
|2019-01-25 12:52:42|
+-------------------+
root
 |-- date_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

2. **`Bucketize the data and find the count for each hour`**

```
 val hour = 60 * 60
    // convert the time into unix epoch
    val processedDF = df.withColumn("unix_epoch", unix_timestamp(col("date_time")))
      .withColumn("hour_bucket", floor(col("unix_epoch")/hour))
      .groupBy("hour_bucket")
      .count()

    processedDF.show(false)
```

Result-

```
+-----------+-----+
|hour_bucket|count|
+-----------+-----+
|423073     |1    |
|423074     |1    |
|423075     |3    |
|423092     |2    |
|423122     |2    |
|430087     |1    |
|430086     |1    |
|430111     |1    |
+-----------+-----+
```

3. **`find hourly average`**

```
  // average count
    processedDF.agg(avg("count")).show(false)
```

Result-

```
+----------+
|avg(count)|
+----------+
|1.5       |
+----------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Someshwar.
Can i do , 
val hour = 60 * 60 * 24 to get Daily Average? and so on?

Comment: You need to divide with 24 * 60 * 60